# Press button (submit) and execute script

Tags: php, html

When variable ($fileName) is not empty - on the page appears one submit button. When is pressed I want script to be executed and all parameters on the page to remain the same..

My attempt:

```
 if(empty($fileName) ) {
   echo "<td><form action='' method='POST'><INPUT TYPE='submit' name='download' VALUE='download'></form></td>\n";
   if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
     $SCRIPT=shell_exec("script.bash $a $b $c");
   }
 } else { echo " <td></td>\n "; }
```

The result should be: the script to start and the page to stay the same (may reloaded but  input parameters to stay). 
But now the page is reloaded and clear all values..

Comment: Where does $a, $b, $c come from?

Comment: _"But now the page is reloaded and clear all values"_ - yes, that's what scripting languages do. They execute a script and exit, don't remember what they have done before. In order to keep the values you'd have to store them somewhere (Session, database, ...)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you need to use Ajax from the form page to request to the current page without reloading. I advise you to use jQuery to correctly implement that. This link [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) will demonstrate how to use the form post without reloading the page. This YouTube video might also help you out: [jQuery Ajax Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ).

One thing to remember is that if you want to send your POST request without the page reloading, you need to add this when you start your function:

```
$(".submit_button").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // This will disable the auto refresh after a form submit

  $.ajax({
    // Your Ajax Code...
  })

})
```

Comment: There is no explanation for how OP can implement this.

Comment: I don't mean to disrespect but I have laid out the foundation of what needs to be done based on the info given. What more should one do?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Look at what you posted and think about what OP would have to do to get anywhere with this. At least supply a simple working example.

Comment: I got you @ryantxr, I don't personally think there needs to be more details so I will leave it at that.

Comment: About the downvote; sorry, that was me. I originally only saw the first paragraph and when I revisited the question, I noticed that there was something else added to the answer. I think that the answer was submitted in haste. I know what I saw, and I was away from the question (my PC actually) maybe a minute before the 5 mins. editing grace without showing edits/revisions...

Comment: (cont'd) I made quick grammar addition and compensated for it. Even though that this was a slight typographical error on the missing quotes, find that it merits my upvote on the added explanation for it. You need to remember that I see a lot of answers that just tell the OP's that they can "do it with this...." on a daily basis, so I hope you understand why that is.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Appreicate you taking the time to fix it and I totally understand. I did originally only posted a simple code but then I re-read his question and added a little more. Apologies didn't mean to make a scene I just thought I forgot something.

Comment: Nah, you didn't make a scene. You were real sport about it. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the post vars, do what you need to do and build the output HTML populating the inputs as needed.

```
<?php

// Assuming you are using PHP 7

$a = $_POST['a'] ?? null;
$b = $_POST['b'] ?? null;
$b = $_POST['c'] ?? null;
// Set up to add the value attributes as needed
// If any of the vars is missing, then it will be null
// so no value will be added to the HTML
$value_a = isset($_POST['a']) ? sprintf('value="%s"', $_POST['a']) : null;
$value_b = isset($_POST['b']) ? sprintf('value="%s"', $_POST['b']) : null;
$value_c = isset($_POST['c']) ? sprintf('value="%s"', $_POST['c']) : null;

if ( isset($_POST['download']) ) {
    $SCRIPT=shell_exec("script.bash $a $b $c");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<div><input type="text" name="a" <?= $value_a ?> ></div>
<div><input type="text" name="b" <?= $value_b ?>  ></div>
<div><input type="text" name="c" <?= $value_c ?>  ></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="download"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Very nice! But actually "$a, $b, $c" are pre-defined parameters. I don't capture user input. Sorry for misunderstanding (forgot to mension)!  My bigger problem is when I've clicked on submit button the page is reloaded and other parameters are gone.. I mean submit button should work like a "link" to start a script :)

Comment: I think found the problem - this FORM is inside other form :( And when I press "inside" submit button (form) other outside FORM is submitted :(